# how to translate only selected XML element using XSL transformer

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces, transform

I am having a XML with custom namespace. I want to write XSTL to transform this input XML to output XML by converting selected element under the namespace other elements remains same in output XML

Example

```
<xml version="1.0">
<a dmlns:abc="http://abc.en.com/abc">
    <abc:A>
        <summary>Books</summary>
    </abc:A>
</a>
```

I want to transform this XML to

```
<xml version="1.0">
<a>
    <sample>
        <summary>Book</summary>
    </sample>
</a>
```

How to write XSTL for this transformation?

Comment: Please provide more details. What does 'selected" mean in this context? And where does the element name "sample" come from?

Comment: I want to parse the XML document using XSTL so that the element <abc:A> was changed to <sample> in the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider the following input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a xmlns:abc="http://abc.en.com/abc">
    <abc:A>
        <summary>Books</summary>
    </abc:A>
    <abc:B>just another element</abc:B>
</a>
```

when this stylesheet is applied:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:abc="http://abc.en.com/abc">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="abc:A">
        <sample>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </sample>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the output is:

```
<a xmlns:abc="http://abc.en.com/abc">

   <sample>

      <summary>Books</summary>

   </sample>

   <abc:B>just another element</abc:B>

</a>
```